# how to create background color for fieldset border

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML. so, i had a doubt how to create a  background color or image for field set border? can i able to use the normal color values for field set or any special color codes are needed for creating background color in field set?
any information will be helpful. i already have a background image for the HTML and i want to apply a background color to the field set border.

Comment: can u provide your html code

Comment: can you be more specific about your code ? you can place your code in [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/), it makes solving your problem easier if we know how you coded

Comment: If you want to color the fieldset background look at Vaibs_Cool's answer, if you want to add a border use fieldset { border: 1px solid black; } You can also use hex colors, e.g.: #000 is black.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5yhq2/

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5yhq2/1/ - added background color and border

Answer (score 5):

> fieldset { 
>       border-color:black;
>       border-style: solid; }

[JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3lackRos3/ECBn9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
fieldset {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
.field_set{
border-color:#F00; //your color here
border-style: solid; //border style
}
```

You can also specify other css properties here as normal css styling

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS code, add:

```
fieldset {
    border: solid red;
}
```

This will make the borders of the `<fieldset>` `red`.
Most standard colors are supported. You can also use hexadecimal values, such as `#FF0000`, which is also red. The first two [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers are the red component, the middle two are the green component, and the last two are the blue component.

To insert an image background, use:

```
fieldset {
    background-image: url('background.png');
}
```

CSS code can be be stored in a file (for example, `style.css`) and included in the `<head>` of a HTML document, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
```

Or directly in your HTML like so:

```
<style>
    /* CSS Code here */
</style>
```